# Custom Facebook Button Image not Centered

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, uibutton, uiimage

I have created a custom Facebook Login Button. Everything works but I can't get the image to center (top/bottom) in the button. The image it self is but when I create this button the image is lower.

```
//FB Button (Uses Facebook SDK)
self.fbLoginButton = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
for (id loginObject in self.fbLoginButton.subviews)
{
    if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton * loginButton =  loginObject;
        UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Facebook_White.png"];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [loginButton setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [loginButton setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [loginButton setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    }
    if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel * loginLabel =  loginObject;
        loginLabel.text = @"";
        loginLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
self.fbLoginButton.delegate = self;
self.fbLoginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];

[[self.fbLoginButton layer]setBorderWidth:2.0];
[[self.fbLoginButton layer]setBorderColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xbbffd6).CGColor];

[buttonsArray addObject:self.fbLoginButton];
```

Here is what it looks like compared to the Twitter Button:

[image]

Here is the actual .png (the text is white so you can't see it unless it is against a background:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I wouldn't use custom Facebook button, but without seeing screenshot/image of your `Facebook_White.png`, I can't tell how to fix it.

Comment: Updated with screens. Sorry I was out of town all week :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around, this is what worked for me. Had to hard code the fbLoginView.frame and the loginButton.frame.

```
//FB Button (Uses Facebook SDK)
self.fbLoginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
self.fbLoginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
self.fbLoginView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35);
[[self.fbLoginView layer]setBorderWidth:2.0];
[[self.fbLoginView layer]setBorderColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xbbffd6).CGColor];

for (id loginObject in self.fbLoginView.subviews)
{
    if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton * loginButton =  loginObject;
        loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.fbLoginView.frame.origin.x, self.fbLoginView.frame.origin.y, 35, 35);
        UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Facebook_White.png"];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel * loginLabel =  loginObject;
        loginLabel.text = @"";
        loginLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}

self.fbLoginView.delegate = self;
[socialButtonsArray addObject:self.fbLoginView];
```